# ezpdf while loop - generating pdf fails

Tags: php, pdf

I've code like that below, what I want to achieve is to generate PDF document with dynamically created rows. It's for users to generate PDF from a form they fill. If they want to put some more text in one of the fields it should have been splitted into rows.

Idea is like that: explode text, and add each word with space after checking if size of it is less than 70 (required chars in a row). Unfortunately there is something wrong with the WHILE loop, causing my script not to generate any PDF file. Can anyone help? I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

```
    //length of line is 70 chars
    $n = strlen($datan['reason']) / 70;

    //if there are some chars left add last line
    if(strlen($datan['reason'])%70 > 0)
    {
        $n++;
    }   
    $pieces = explode(" ",$datan['reason']);
    $piece_number = 0;

    //create n lines 
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
        $previous = "";
        $l = true;
        //add pieces not to exceed 70 chars
        while($l == true){
            $current = $pieces[$piece_number];
            if(strlen($current) + strlen($previous) < 70){
                $previous .= $current . " ";
                $piece_number++;
            }
            else
                $l = false;
        }
        //print line
        $pdf->addText(215,535+(20*$i),10,$previous);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, problem was in the while as I expected, it couldn't end because it ran out of $pieces array and I forgot to control that.